# String substitution does not work for first occurence

Tags: java, apache-commons

I have to substitute some template with textual and json values.

My problem :The first substitution value is not substituted.

I have following code:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;

public class TestStringSubstitutor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> jsonParameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("entityId", "someid");
    parameters.put("name", "someName");
    parameters.put("now", ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT).toString());

    jsonParameters.put("info", "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"car\":null}");


    String template = "{\"description\":\"this is ja unit test\",\"time\":\"{now}\",\"name\":\"{name}\",\"entityId\":\"{entityId}\",\"info\":\"{{info}}\"}";
    System.out.println("           template:" + template);

    String modMessage = StringSubstitutor.replace(template, parameters, "{", "}");
    System.out.println("replaced Message #1:" + modMessage);

    modMessage = StringSubstitutor.replace(modMessage, jsonParameters, "\"{{", "}}\"");
    System.out.println("replaced Message #2:" + modMessage);
  }

}
```

The output:

```
           template:{"description":"this is a unit test","time":"{now}","name":"{name}","entityId":"{entityId}","info":"{{info}}"}
replaced Message #1:{"description":"this is a unit test","time":"{now}","name":"someName","entityId":"someid","info":"{{info}}"}
replaced Message #2:{"description":"this is a unit test","time":"{now}","name":"someName","entityId":"someid","info":{"name":"John","age":30,"car":null}}
```

---

**Problem
{now} should be substituted...**

If I change the order of template:  name <--> time

```
String template = "{\"description\":\"this is a unit test\",\"name\":\"{name}\",\"time\":\"{now}\",\"entityId\":\"{entityId}\",\"info\":\"{{info}}\"}";
```

then the output changes, {now} is substituted, but the first substitution value {name} is still not substituted.

```
           template:{"description":"this is a unit test","name":"{name}","time":"{now}","entityId":"{entityId}","info":"{{info}}"}
replaced Message #1:{"description":"this is a unit test","name":"{name}","time":"2019-10-01T08:35:10.961177100Z","entityId":"someid","info":"{{info}}"}
replaced Message #2:{"description":"this is a unit test","name":"{name}","time":"2019-10-01T08:35:10.961177100Z","entityId":"someid","info":{"name":"John","age":30,"car":null}}
```

Is this a bug or do I miss something?

Comment: You should be using a JSON parser here, not simple (or even regex) string substitution.

Comment: I am pretty sure this happens because your prefix is not unique in the string so the first variable found in the template is `{\"description..."{now}` which doesn't match any of the keys in `parameters`. As said by @TimBiegeleisen. this is json so parse it as json.

Comment: From application view, this is just plain text. Maybe this could be also a markdown text with json parts...

Comment: Ok but you still have the problem with your prefix not being unique so this might not be a workable solution.

Comment: put a breakpoint in StringSubstitutor class line 458. And you will see the problem what @JoakimDanielson explained.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint from [joakim-danielson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9223839/joakim-danielson) solved the problem. The prefix '{' and  suffix '}' is not unique.

Now using '{{' and '}}'.

Here is a working example:

```
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.commons.text.StringSubstitutor;

public class TestStringSubstitutor {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new HashMap<>();
    Map<String, String> jsonParameters = new HashMap<>();
    parameters.put("entityId", "someid");
    parameters.put("name", "someName");
    parameters.put("now", ZonedDateTime.now().format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_INSTANT).toString());

    jsonParameters.put("info", "{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"car\":null}");


    String template = "{\"name\":\"{{name}}\",\"time\":\"{{now}}\",\"entityId\":\"{{entityId}}\",\"info\":\"{{info}}\", \"description\":\"this is a unit test\"}";
    System.out.println("           template:" + template);

    String modMessage = StringSubstitutor.replace(template, parameters, "{{", "}}");
    System.out.println("replaced Message #1:" + modMessage);

    modMessage = StringSubstitutor.replace(modMessage, jsonParameters, "\"{{", "}}\"");
    System.out.println("replaced Message #2:" + modMessage);
  }

}
```

Output

```
           template:{"name":"{{name}}","time":"{{now}}","entityId":"{{entityId}}","info":"{{info}}", "description":"this is a unit test"}
replaced Message #1:{"name":"someName","time":"2019-10-01T10:56:54.991583700Z","entityId":"someid","info":"{{info}}", "description":"this is a unit test"}
replaced Message #2:{"name":"someName","time":"2019-10-01T10:56:54.991583700Z","entityId":"someid","info":{"name":"John","age":30,"car":null}, "description":"this is a unit test"}
```